# Can I strip carriage returns as they go into a `std::stringstream`?

Tags: c++, iostream, line-endings

```
struct T
{
   void eat(std::string const& segment)
   {
      buffer << segment;

      std::string sentence;
      while (std::getline(buffer, sentence))
         std::cout << "[" << sentence.size() << "]";
   }

   std::stringstream buffer;
};

int main() {
   T t;
   t.eat("A\r\nB\nC\nD");
//        ^^   ^  ^  ^
}

// Actual output:  [2][1][1][1]
// Desired output: [1][1][1][1]
```

I would like the `std::stringstream` to strip that carriage return for me (and would prefer not to have to copy and modify `segment`).

How might I go about this? I would have thought that this would happen anyway, on Linux, for a stream in text mode... but perhaps that mechanism is in the logic of *file* streams.

Comment: I suppose I could just stream in a character at a time, ignoring `\r`. I cba to benchmark it, but I wonder whether I lose any speed doing that.

Comment: You could use a modified getline function like the ones in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089231/getting-std-ifstream-to-handle-lf-cr-and-crlf).

Comment: Is it the case there could be other whitespace present in the strings that are `eat`en ?

Comment: @hmjd: Usually no, but I'm not confident enough about that to employ `std::skipws`.

Comment: `std::skipws` isn't a solution, because it only removes leading white space (and the '\015' from Windows will normally appear as trailing) and is ignored by unformatted input functions like `getline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general problem on Unix machines when reading files created on
a Windows machine.  I would suggest doing the clean-up at the input
level.

One of the best solution I've found when reading line based files is to
create a class something like:

```
class Line
{
    std::string myText;
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& source, Line& dest )
    {
        std::getline( source, dest.myText );
        if ( source ) {
            dest.myText.erase( 
                std::remove( dest.myText.begin(), dest.myText.end(), '\015' ),
                dest.myText.end() );
        }
        return source;
    }

    operator std::string() const
    {
        return myText;
    }
};
```

You can add other functions as necessary: the automatic type conversion
doesn't play when trying to match templates, for example, and I found it
useful to add friends to wrap `boost::regex_match`.

I use this (without the `'\015'` removal) even when I don't have to
worry about Windows/Linux differences; it supports reading lines using
`std::istream_iterator<Line>`, for example.

Another solution would be to use a filtering streambuf, inserted into
the input stream.  This is also very simple:

```
class RemoveCRStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* mySource;
    char myBuffer;  //  One char buffer required for input.
protected:
    int underflow()
    {
        int results = mySource->sbumpc();
        while ( results == '\015' ) {
            results = mySource->sbumpc();
        }
        if ( results != EOF ) {
            myBuffer = results;
            setg( &myBuffer, &myBuffer + 1, &myBuffer + 1 );
        }
        return results;
    }

public:
    RemoveCRStreambuf( std::streambuf* source )
        : mySource( source )
    {
    }
};
```

To insert it:

```
std::streambuf* originalSB = source->rdbuf();
RemoveCRStreambuf newSB( originalSB );
source->rdbuf( &newSB );
//  Do input here...
source->rdbuf( originalSB );    //  Restore...
```

(Obviously, using some sort of RAII for the restoration would be
preferable.  My own filtering streambuf have a constructor which takes
an `std::istream`; they save a pointer to this as well, and restore the
streambuf in their destructor.)