# Getline to String Copies newline as well

Tags: c++, string, file-io, newline

I am reading a file line by line and adding each line to a string. However the string length increases by 1 for every line which I believe is due to newline character. How can I remove it from being copied.

Here is my code attempt to do the same.

```
if (inputFile.is_open())
{
    {
        string currentLine;
        while (!inputFile.eof())
            while( getline( inputFile, currentLine ) )
            {
                string s1=currentLine;
                cout<<s1.length();
            }
```

[Updated Description] i have used notepad++ to determine the length of what i am selecting line by line. So they are showing some 123, 450, 500, 120 for which my program shows 124,451,501,120. Except for the last line, all line.length() shows an increased by 1 value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I formatted your code for you. The first one's free. After that you have to buy me a pint ;-)

Comment: `std::getline()` discards the newline character. How do you determine the expected line length?

Comment: Using                 cout<<s1.length();

Comment: That is the line length read by `std::getline()`, which appears to be different to what you expect,

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue of the newline on different plattforms? Where comes the file from, on which platform you wrote your program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `inputFile` has Windows-style [line-breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/line-breaks/info) (CRLF) but your program is splitting the input on Unix-like line-breaks (LF), because [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), breaks on `\n` by default, leaving the CR (`\r`) at the end of your string.

You'll need to trim the extraneous `\r`s. Here is one way to do it, along with a small test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

void remove_carriage_return(std::string& line)
{
    if (*line.rbegin() == '\r')
    {
        line.erase(line.length() - 1);
    }
}

void find_line_lengths(std::istream& inputFile, std::ostream& output)
{
    std::string currentLine;
    while (std::getline(inputFile, currentLine))
    {
        remove_carriage_return(currentLine);
        output
            << "The current line is "
            << currentLine.length()
            << " characters long and ends with '0x"
            << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex
            << static_cast<int>(*currentLine.rbegin())
            << "'"
            << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream test_data(
        "\n"
        "1\n"
        "12\n"
        "123\n"
        "\r\n"
        "1\r\n"
        "12\r\n"
        "123\r\n"
        );

    find_line_lengths(test_data, std::cout);
}
```

Output:

```
The current line is 0 characters long and ends with '0x00'
The current line is 1 characters long and ends with '0x31'
The current line is 2 characters long and ends with '0x32'
The current line is 3 characters long and ends with '0x33'
The current line is 0 characters long and ends with '0x00'
The current line is 1 characters long and ends with '0x31'
The current line is 2 characters long and ends with '0x32'
The current line is 3 characters long and ends with '0x33'
```

Things to note:

- You don't need to test for EOF. [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will return the stream, which will cast to `false` when it can read no more from `inputFile`.
- You don't need to copy a string to determine its length.

Comment: i have used npp++ to determine the length of what i am selecting line by line. So they are showing some 123, 450, 500, 120 for which my program shows 124,451,501,120. Except for the last line, all line.length() shows an increased by 1 value.

Comment: Can you run your program against a much smaller test file with line-lengths you can count manually? What does it report for lines of zero-length? (Mine reports 0)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're under MS-Windows and they add a "\r" before the "\n" and that "\r" is not removed.

Comment: That is not correct, `\r` is also removed (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6089413/237483), but it's an issue, if the file is stored under Windows and read under Linux.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer I would bet big bucks that this **is** the issue! Sure, when reading a file in text mode on a Windows machine, the end of line sequence is replaced by a `\n` which is stripped but this nice invisible character at the end of each line easily messes the reads up. It is simple to verify if this is case: `if (!s.empty() && s.back() == '\r') { std::cout << "gotcha!\n"; }`

Comment: @Dietmar: Maybe not for you, but for me it's an issue (Client = Windows, Server = Linux), and it seems that in the OPs case, this was really the reason.

Comment: @Christian Actually if you open the file in binary mode (which is probably not the case here...) then the \r\n would not be transformed either under MS-Windows. Whether getline() is smart enough to do that work anyway, I am not 100% sure though.