# comparison of strings does not work

Tags: c++, comparison, stdstring

I have a code as below. Whenever `temps = $Nodes` loop should end. I checked `temps` every in iteration and saw that `temps = $Nodes` once as expected but the loop was not ended. This code worked for VS10 but not working for linux. Any idea?

```
std::string temps;
s_mesh_file.open (mesh_file.c_str());

do
{
    getline (s_mesh_file, temps);
    std::cout << "temps: " << temps << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
}
while (temps != "$Nodes");
```

Comment: Maybe `temps` contains some trailing white spaces at the end? So you see "`$Nodes`" on your window but it's actually "`$Nodes `"?

Comment: Are they using the same exact input file?  Including with Windows newlines?  Linux doesn't like windows newlines. (Nor does Windows like Linux's)  @AndyProwl it's probably `"$Nodes\r"`

Comment: I guess this is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960119/112968

Comment: Have you checked that the string is **exactly** as expected (i.e. no invisible characters like spaces at the end or similar changes?)

Comment: try `std::cout << "temps: '" << temps << "'" << std::endl;` and check for additional whitespaces

Comment: @h3nr1x, Good start, but no invisible characters. Print the length as well.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Aha! That was the problem. I created a new file and copy pasted the content again instead of copying the file itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are they using the same exact input file? Including with Windows newlines? Linux doesn't like windows newlines. (Nor does Windows like Linux's)

In windows, each newline is a `\r` followed by an `\n`.  In Linux, a newline is *just* `\n`.  Streams open by default in "text mode" which converts whatever the system newline is into just `\n`.  So, when you read the file in Windows, it's dropping the `\r` helpfully. However, Linux doesn't realize it's part of the newline, and so is putting the `\r` onto the end of your string like any other normal character, which makes it not match the hardcoded `"$Nodes"`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `std::cin.ignore();`. You are waiting for user input actually. Tested on linux.

Comment: You must've missed the comments. I didn't even notice that was for `cin` until a short while ago, so I was confused why the OP was getting correct text. I strongly believe the OP is pressing enter on each iteration.