# resulting string from sprintf has different order of values than passed oder of parameters on Ubuntu server

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, file-io, printf

I am reading filenames written in a text file into a string vector. For each file name I want to create its complete path so that I can read it. For final path I merge 'Map_PATH' and 'filenames' variables together into FileName (char array) using sprintf function.

Now on windows its shows FileName contains "/data2/worcester_000187.txt" which is what I needed. But running it on Ubuntu server gives a result ".txta2/worcester_000187" instead, it overwritten data2 partially. Text file contains file names like this i.e. Single name on each line:

```
worcester_000187
worcester_000192
worcester_000193
worcester_000194
worcester_000196
worcester_000197
worcester_000198
```

What I found that if I assign 'filename' string variable with a hard coded values say:

```
filename="worcester_000187";
```

I get the right results. But it creates problem when same filename variable gets a string values read from text file. Either there is some problem with reading with file.

Below a highlight of code is given:

```
char FileName[500];
char Map_PATH[]="/data2/";
vector < string > fileList;
string filename;
fstream fp;

fp.open ("ImagesListTemp.txt", ios::in);
if(!fp.is_open())
{
cerr <<"Unable to open Image Names List: "<<endl;
exit(1);
}


while (getline(fp, filename)) 
{
fileList.push_back(filename);
}
fp.close();



for(int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++)
{
 filename=fileList[i];
 //    filename="worcester_000187"; 
 sprintf(FileName,"%s%s.txt",Map_PATH,filename.c_str()); 
 // Open File and do some operations

}
```

Comment: that is a big mix between c and c++ :(

Comment: Made some changes. Still has same problem.

Comment: I test it， the code seems fine

Comment: It works fine on windows but when I run on Ubuntu server using g++ it gives *.txta2/worcester_000187* as output for a particular file. Notice how .txt moved in start. I still have this problem.

Comment: @itwasntpete, Even I tried with this still has same problem. Seems there is something wrong when I read data from file.

ostringstream out;

out<<Map_PATH<<filename.c_str()<<"/"<<".txt\0";

cout<<"From new \n "<<out.str()<<endl;

Comment: @itwasntpete I found the problem. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As anticipated the problem was with the text file. Here is what was happening.

1. A text file written in windows (I wrote text file in windows) takes  CR and LF **(\r\n)** as line ending.
2. Linux and Unix considers just LF (\n) as line ending.
3. When running on Linux **getline()** detects **\n** to detect end of line and filename gets **"worcester_000187\r"** as value. Notice extra carriage return added.
4. Following statement  **sprintf(FileName,"%s%s.txt",Map_PATH,filename.c_str())** can be assessed in two steps i.e. before and after we reach to '.txt'
5. Before '.txt'  FileName contains **'/data2/worcester_000187\r'** . Now **'\r'** brings us back to start of this line again.
6. Now we add **.txt** and cursor is in the start and hence it overwrites first four characters in **'FileName'** array. I hope it makes sense.

Using **dos2unix** command converts text file to the desired format.

Comment: Hmm, nasty. Solved, however, I would make the file reading platform independent by *explicitly* testing for n `\r`, and removing if found.

Comment: Following post suggests a very nice solution for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089231/getting-std-ifstream-to-handle-lf-cr-and-crlf/6089413#6089413