# Reading of text file in Ubuntu has extra //r

Tags: c++, debugging, ubuntu, carriage-return

I am porting a program created in C++ from MS Studio to Ubuntu . The program works fine except when it reads from a text file .

My text file consists of lines of information seperated by the delimiter `:`

```
General Manager:G001:def
Customer:C001:def:Lim:Tom:Mr:99999999:zor@hotmail.com:Blk 145 B North #03-03 Singapore 111111
```

**Read method**

```
while (getline(afile,line,'\n')) //read line and store string in variable line
        {


            stringstream ss(line);
            string s;
            while (getline(ss,s,':'))
            {
                word.push_back(s);
            }


            word.clear();

        }
```

On Windows platform , it is stored correctly as `def`

However on Ubuntu platform , it is stored as `def\\r`

It works fine for C`ustomer Record` but gives problem for `General Manager`

I know it has something to do with [Carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) but I am not sure how to resolve it

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089231/getting-std-ifstream-to-handle-lf-cr-and-crlf

Answer (score 0):

If the text file was created on Windows, you can use the [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) command to remove the extra \r's from the file. The command is simply `dos2unix filenamegoeshere`

Comment: Why is it \\r and not \r

Comment: The input file will have \r, but I don't know why it gets converted to \\r.

Comment: Assuming the txt file name :User.txt , I am typing "dos2unix User.txt" , it doesnt work

Comment: In a command prompt, right, not in the program? Also you need to `cd /path/to/file/goes/here` first, sorry I forgot to say that.