# How to detect a CRLF in a stream

Tags: c++, iostream

I got a stringstream of with HTTP request content. As you know HTTP request end up with CRLF break. But operator>> won't recognize CRLF as if it's a normal end-of-file.
How can I detect this CRLF break?

**EDIT:**
All right, actually I'm using boost.iostreams. But I don't think there should be any differences.

```
char head[]     = "GET / HTTP1.1\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)\r\nHost: www.baidu.com\r\n\r\n";
io::stream<My_InOut>    in(head, sizeof head);
string s;
while(in >> s){
        char c = in.peek(); // what I am doing here is to check if next character is a normal break so that 's' is a complete word.
        switch( c ){
        case -1:
              // is it eof or an incomplete word?
              break;
        case 0x20: // a complete word
              break;
        case 0x0d:
        case 0x0a: // also known as \r\n should indicate a complete word
              break;
}
```

In this code, I assume that the request could possibly be split into parts because of its transmission, so I wanted to recognize whether '-1' stand for actual end-of-request or just a break word that I need to read more to complete the request.

Comment: at the end of file you should get -1 as end of file marker

Comment: Probably he/she meant EOL instead of EOF.

Comment: I don't think -1 can fully point out my cases, so I need to find a far more reliable way.

Comment: You should be able to get the content length in the request and just read the amount of specified bytes.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6089413/402169

Comment: did you try to read full stream? what is the output ?

Comment: Open the stream in binary, use `std::getline`; then parse for spaces.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `peek` returns an `int`, not a `char` (at least, `std::istream::peek` returns `int`--I don't know about boost).  This distinction is important for recognizing -1 as the end of the file rather than a character with the value of `0xFF`.

Also be aware that i/o streams in text mode will transform the platform's line separator into `'\n'` (which, in C and C++, [usually has the same value as a line feed, but it might not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n/9549183#9549183)).  So if you're running this on Windows, where the native line separator is CR+LF, you'll never see the CR.  But if you run the same code on a Linux box, where the native separator is simply LF, you will.

So given your question:

> How can I detect this CRLF break?

The answer is to open the stream in binary mode and check for the character values `0x0D` followed by `0x0A`.

That said, it's not unheard of for HTML code to overlook that the network protocol requires CR+LF.  If you want to be abide by the "be liberal in what you accept" maxim, you just watch for either CR or LF and then skip the next character if it's the complement.