# C++ string formatting - fixed width floating point, and string with spaces at offset

Tags: c++

I'm playing around with stringstreams, and I've got a line like:

```
10 651.23 Some longer name
```

I'd like to fetch it into uint, double and string like 10, 651.23, "Some longer name"

So I've tried

```
    iss >> quantity >> price >> std::noskipws >> name;
```

But it seems it isn't so easy as it looks. How can I get rest of the string including whitespaces?

Later I want to show the float with leading character and fixed precision:

```
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << std::setw(7) << std::setfill('.') << price;
```

However when I use std::fixed, my fill and width get rejected. How to fix that?

Thanks

Current code:

```
std::string filename;

std::ifstream is;
do {

    std::cout << "Podaj nazwę pliku do wczytania: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> filename;
    is.open(filename.c_str());

    if(is.good()) break;
} while(true);

std::string name;
std::string wtf;
unsigned int quantity = 0;
double price = 0;
unsigned int i = 1;

while(is >> quantity >> price >> std::ws && std::getline(is, name)) {
    std::cout << "| ";
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << i++ << " | ";
    std::cout << std::setw(30) << std::setfill('.') << name << " | ";
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::setfill(' ') << quantity << " x ";
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::setw(10) << std::setfill(' ') << std::fixed << price << " zl | ";
    std::cout << std::setw(11) << std::setfill(' ') << quantity * price << " zl |";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The file looks like:

```
10 12999 TV55AA8000 smarttv ultra HD
5 12990 TV55AB600 smarttv ultraHD
20 9999 TV55GD2340s smarttv
10 7999 TV463400 funkcja 3D
20 1699.5 telewizor super!
30 1400 telewizor 3d 1000Hz
20 12999 telewizor nr 1
30 12000 EE55650 smarttv
10 1000 ED325400s
10 14350.00 EE80234
5 5600.00 TV60ED23231 smart tv plazma
10 2000.00 TV320323
1 12999.00 TV66EE231231 smarttv
12 3400.00 TV4243dss 3D
```

Comment: Tried putting `std::setw(7) << std::setfill('.') <<` before `std::fixed`? Just a shot in the dark ...

Comment: Magic, I had it like this previously (or maybe not, as it looks ok now). If you can help me with other problem, post an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: I didn't think about closing this answer. I'll post one if you don't wan to delete your question and the above comment solved it. I think it's useful for s.o. else, if no one else finds a duplicate that already applies.

Comment: As for your other concerns I've posted an answer meant as canonical once, which is meant to solve problems about how to read from structured input records: [Why does reading a struct record fields from std::istream fail, and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi)

Comment: You'll need to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for the formatting problem: according to [my test](http://ideone.com/T8pf3M) setting the formatting flags like above just works.

Comment: Added current code. Thanks

Comment: You code is still not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)! [Here](http://ideone.com/KNJsjG) is my rendering of exactly your code *not* showing the problem, though!

Comment: Hm, with your stringstream it works like a charm. I can't use ideone as this requires file input... Updated the thread

Comment: @Misiur _' I can't use ideone as this requires file input...'_ This could be usually replaced with `std::cin` somehow ...

Comment: Yup, but the thing is with mock stringstream/cin it works! Could the fact that file has windows \r\n line endings and I'm working on unix be a issue here?
#e: Yup, that's the reason! But: is there a way to autodetect those endings so it works cross-platform, line-endings style independent?
#e2: Oh, [found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089231/getting-std-ifstream-to-handle-lf-cr-and-crlf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To incude whitespace when reading strings you can either change the definition of whitespace means (yes, this *can* be done by replacing the `std::ctype<char>` facet in a new `std::locale` and `imbue()`ing the stream with the thus constructed `std::locale`) or, a bit simpler, by using `std::getline()` to read the rest of the line. Assuming you want to ignore the leading whitespace in front of the trailing characters, you'd use `std::ws` when switching between formatted and unformatted input:

```
if (std::getline(iss >> quantity >> price >> std::ws, name)) {
    // do something with the result
}
```

I can't write input statements like the above without checking as I firmly believe that input shall always be verified for success after it is done.

The purpose of `std::noskipws` is to disable automatic skipping of whitespace by formatted input operations: the formatted input operations skip leading whitespace by default. However, the flag has no effect at all on how strings are are parsed except for skipping leading whitespace. With the `std::noskipws` flag set I'd think you'll just read an empty string as the extraction immediately finds a character not matching the formatting and stops.

With respect to the `std::fixed` settings for output I'm pretty sure that the setting should work but right now I can't verify what's going on.

Comment: _'but right now I can't verify what's going on'_ Same for me :/, I'm a bit worrying I can't provide some facts, why it works the one way, but not the other.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: if it depends on the order the flags are set I can only imagine that the implementation internally uses `snprintf()` and caches the formatting flags to be use, messing the settings up at some point.

Comment: Hm, I understand how this solution works, but it doesn't for some reason? When I check for !std::getline(iss >> quantity >> price >> std::ws, name)), the name is populated, but otherwise it is empty? My frontend mind can't grasp some C++ concepts, sorry. Should I include bigger slice of code?

Comment: @Misiur: You should **not** negate the result to test for a successful read! The stream will convert to `true` if it its input operations were successful. ... and I'm pretty sure that my approach does works based on [my test](http://ideone.com/hmPhHT).

Comment: Good tip, I didn't check return type earlier. Now I've added current code, approach taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/23047405/309240 .  Something is still wrong though, name is not populated at all

Answer (score 3):

You may try placing the `std::setw(7) << std::setfill('.') <<` manipulators before the `std::fixed` manipulator

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::setw(7) << std::setfill('.') 
          << std::fixed << price;
```

But as for the standard definitions this shouldn't really matter.
Looks like this is a possible bug of your actual toolchain.

Comment: If the order of how these formatting flags are set matters, there is something wrong with the corresponding implementation! These flags can be set independently and are inspected (by `std::num_put<...>::do_put()`) when formatting the value. The only flag which is a bit different is the width as it gets reset after each output operation using it but none of these operations other than formatting the `price` uses the width.