# How to detect a line break in C++?

Tags: c++, std

in windows, a line break is

```
\r\n
```

in linux,

```
\n
```

I don't want to change my code when it runs in different OS, I just want to recompile it directly.

So how to detect it in C++? Did the standard library defined a constant or function to detect it?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, I imagine looking for `std::endl` would work

Comment: Just read string from file @VoidStar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform dependent details you need to encapsulate in abstraction. So just provide simple class `TextInfo` (?) and add there static function or maybe public static member which will return the line ending.

In this function you can add platform specific code with conditional compilation using preprocesor defines.

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
return "\r\n";
#endif
#ifdef LINUX
return "\n";
#endif
```

Now you just need to provide different target compilations (probably you already have that). For targets you need to add one more define to compile command (-D for gcc and /D for VS).

Then in code you are able to use `TextInfo` which will work fine for both systems. At any time you are able to add additional systems.

Comment: You are wrong.
#ifdef LINUX doesn't work at all,
you should replace it with #ifdef unix,
And #ifdef WINDOWS also is wrong, replace it with #ifdef WIN32

Comment: Pleas read the whole answer. Also with this part: `For targets you need to add one more define to compile command.` I don't use 'standard' defines because there are compilator dependent. Provide you own by adding them to compile command.

Comment: I got your idea. But please use the standard.

Comment: And I want to know, whether the standard library defined similar class?

Comment: But there are no standard defines like these! And that's why I put it in quotes. In different compiler you will need to use different macro to check that so best way is to provide own. Both macros which you shown are compiler-specific macro. You like to have generality in newline using compiler-specific macros?

Comment: There are no standard class for that and there is no standard class for difference in '\' and '/' on unix and windows directories :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't *have* to change your code. Each implementation will correctly handle it's own line endings.

Provided each platform read and writes its *own* files, it will work fine.

The only problem you'll have is if you transfer a Windows-style *data file* to UNIX or vice versa. If *that's* the sort of thing you're doing, you can simply modify the string that you read in so that any `\r` character at the end is removed.

Note that *won't* adversely affect Windows-style files since, in memory, they don't *have* the `\r` - it's only put in the file when writing.

Comment: Uhm it depends if you read the content on binary mode or text mode, additionally network protocols like http/smtp use \r\n to specify the new line. If he uses only text mode, you are completely right, if he mixes binary/text mode, he should be really careful with this aspect, and as I said, if he works with network protocols, he should consider them.

Comment: I don't think you need to bother about reading UNIX files on Windows, - the C library usually ignores the missing `\r`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't move your files between Windows/Linux, you should be fine.

However, in many circumstances, you have to read both conventions from both compiled programs. This is common with all sorts of documents and some network protocols. If this is the case, I recommend the following procedure:

1. Scan for `\r` or `\n`.
2. If char found is `\r`, then also look for `\n` immediately after it. If it exists, then consume it as part of the same newline.

This scanning procedure will accept files with `CR`, `LF`, and `CR+LF` line endings. It is analogous to what many encoding-detecting higher level string streams do.

Here is another answer which outlines this procedure in code for `istream`:
[Getting std :: ifstream to handle LF, CR, and CRLF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089231/getting-std-ifstream-to-handle-lf-cr-and-crlf)

Comment: Is there any other line break symbol ?

Comment: More exist, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline . But IMO they are not worth supportong. `CR`, `LF`, and `CR+LF` are the big 3 for general multiplatform support.