# Using a regex_iterator on an istream

Tags: c++, regex, iterator, istream, istream-iterator

I want to be able to solve problems like this: [Getting std :: ifstream to handle LF, CR, and CRLF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089231/2642059) where an `istream` needs to be tokenized by a complex delimiter; such that the only way to tokenize the `istream` is to:

1. Read it in the `istream` a character at a time
2. Collect the characters
3. When a delimiter is hit return the collection as a token

Regexes are very good at tokenizing strings with complex delimiters:

```
string foo{ "A\nB\rC\n\r" };
vector<string> bar;

// This puts {"A", "B", "C"} into bar
transform(sregex_iterator(foo.cbegin(), foo.cend(), regex("(.*)(?:\n\r?|\r)")), sregex_iterator(), back_inserter(bar), [](const smatch& i){ return i[1].str(); });
```

But I can't use a `regex_iterator` on a `istream` :( My solution has been to slurp the `istream` and then run the `regex_iterator` over it, but the slurping step seems superfluous.

Is there an unholy combination of `istream_iterator` and `regex_iterator` out there somewhere, or if I want it do I have to write it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is about code appearance:

1. Since we know that a `regex` will work 1 character at a time, this question is asking to use a library to parse the `istream` 1 character at a time rather than internally reading and parsing the `istream` 1 character at a time
2. Since parsing an `istream` 1 character at a time will still copy that one character to a temp variable (buffer) this code seeks to avoid buffering all the code internally, depending on a library instead to abstract that

---

C++11's `regex`es use ECMA-262 which does not support look aheads or look behinds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14539500/2642059 This means that a `regex` could match using only an `input_iterator_tag`, but clearly those implemented in C++11 do not.

`boost::regex_iterator` on the other hand does support the `boost::match_partial` flag (which is [not available in C++11 `regex` flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type).) `boost::match_partial` allows the user to slurp *part* of the file and run the `regex` over that, on a mismatch due to end of input the `regex` will "hold it's finger" at that position in the regex and await more being added to the buffer. You can see an example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/partial_matches.html In the average case, like `"A\nB\rC\n\r"`, this can save buffer size.

`boost::match_partial` has 4 drawbacks:

1. In the worst case, like `"ABC\n"` this saves the user *no* size and he must slurp the whole `istream`
2. If the programmer can guess a buffer size that is too large, that is it contains the delimiter and a significant amount more, the benefits of the reduction in buffer size are squandered
3. Any time the buffer size selected is too small, additional computations will be required compared to the slurping of the entire file, therefore this method excels in a delimiter-dense string
4. The inclusion of `boost` always causes bloat

Circling back to answer the question: A standard library `regex_iterator` cannot operate on an `input_iterator_tag`, slurping of the whole `istream` required. A `boost::regex_iterator` allows the user to *possibly* slurp less than the whole `istream`. Because this is a question about code appearance though, and because `boost::regex_iterator`'s worst case requires slurping of the whole file anyway,  it is not a good answer to this question.

For the best code appearance slurping the whole file and running a standard `regex_iterator` over it is your best bet.

Comment: "C++11's regexes use ECMA-262 which does not support look aheads or look behinds".

It indeed doesn't support look behinds but C++ *do* support *look aheads* : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think not. `istream_iterator` has the `input_iterator_tag` tag, whereas `regex_iterator` expects to be initialized using bi-directional iterators (`bidirectional_iterator_tag`).

If your delimiter regex is complex enough to avoid reading the stream yourself, the best way to do this is to indeed slurp the `istream`.