# Visual Studio regex_iterator Bug?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-studio-2013, assertion

I'm on Visual Studio 2013 and I'm seeing what I think is a bug, I was hoping someone could confirm?

```
string foo{ "A\nB\rC\n\r" };
vector<string> bar;

for (sregex_iterator i(foo.cbegin(), foo.cend(), regex("(.*)[\n\r]{1,2}")); i != sregex_iterator(); ++i){
    bar.push_back(i->operator[](1).str());
}
```

This code hits a Debug Assertion in the Visual Studio regex library:

> `regex_iterator` orphaned

If I define the `regex` outside the `for`-loop it's fine:

```
string foo{ "A\nB\rC\n\r" };
vector<string> bar;
regex bug("(.*)[\n\r]{1,2}");

for (sregex_iterator i(foo.cbegin(), foo.cend(), bug); i != sregex_iterator(); ++i){
    bar.push_back(i->operator[](1).str());
}
```

Alternatively this works fine in a transform as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29895519/2642059):

```
string foo{ "A\nB\rC\n\r" };
vector<string> bar;

// This puts {"A", "B", "C"} into bar
transform(sregex_iterator(foo.cbegin(), foo.cend(), regex("(.*)[\n\r]{1,2}")), sregex_iterator(), back_inserter(bar), [](const smatch& i){ return i[1].str(); });
```

Can someone confirm this is a bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++11 you are allowed to bind a temporary `regex` to `const regex &` which can lead to undefined behavior if the iterator is used outside of the lifetime of the temporary since it will store a pointer to it. This is a defect in the specification and it is not an error, although Visual Studio catches this with a debug assert.

```
sregex_iterator i(foo.cbegin(), foo.cend(), regex("(.*)[\n\r]{1,2}"))
                                            ^^^^^
                                            temporary
```

The following deleted overload was adding in C++14 to prevent this case, from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator/regex_iterator):

```
regex_iterator(BidirIt, BidirIt,
           const regex_type&&,
           std::regex_constants::match_flag_type =
           std::regex_constants::match_default) = delete;       (since C++14)
```

and it says:

> The overload 2 is not allowed to be called with a temporary regex,
>   since the returned iterator would be immediately invalidated.

So this is not a `Visual Studio` bug since it is implementing the C++11 standard and this was not addressed via a defect report till later on. Both `clang` and `gcc` using `-std=c++14` or greater will produce an error with your first(*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gepU41fsWrHBgHm2)*) and third(*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/a8WYGC64U2uXr9vX)*) example. Visual Studio only started supporting some C++14 in [VS 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-preview-vs.aspx):

> [...]and initial support for certain C++14 features.[...]

We can see that [LWG defect 2332: regex_iterator/regex_token_iterator should forbid temporary regexes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2332) deals with this:

> Users can write "for(sregex_iterator i(s.begin(), s.end(),
>   regex("meow")), end; i != end; ++i)", binding a temporary regex to
>   const regex& and storing a pointer to it. This will compile silently,
>   triggering undefined behavior at runtime. We now have the technology
>   to prevent this from compiling, like how reference_wrapper refuses to
>   bind to temporaries.

As T.C. points out the last example you show is actually ok, even though you are binding a temporary its lifetime extends to the end of the expression.

Comment: So what you're saying is the fact it compiled is a bug? And the fact that I could do the `transform` statement is a bug?

Comment: @JonathanMee: the fact that it compiled means VS 2013 mostly tries to implement C++11, not C++14. The fact that the `transform` worked isn't really a bug. You used a temporary after it was destroyed. That's undefined behavior, so the compiler can do *anything* and still conform with the standard.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Interesting I guess that's the problem with not totally supporting any one standard. I had certainly assumed that the move constructor would hang onto the `regex`.

Comment: When you say: "The behavior for cases 1 and 3" You're talking about the `regex_iterator`s that were constructed by moving a `regex` right? I'm still not following why I didn't get a compile time error since these were `delete`d unless @JerryCoffin 's suggestion is the problem. If that's the case, maybe you could add a note in your answer?

Comment: @JonathanMee updated, I realized, it was not clear on several points.

Comment: @JonathanMee - Note that LWG2332 was reported by Microsoft when the problem was discovered. And that was *after* the release of VS2013. What can you do?

Comment: @BoPersson How do we know that the bug was submitted by Microsoft? I mean it doesn't seem likely to have been submitted by gcc given their slowness to implement `regex` stuff, but still...

Comment: @JonathanMee STL(Stephan T. Lavavej) works at MS and is very involved on the committee

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour STL in this case referring to "Stephan T. Lavavej" I'm sure... or you were making a funny joke. I feel like you guys are so much cooler than me... you're on a first name basis with the guys building compilers!

Comment: @JonathanMee I am just a geek and I follow C++ closely, he is well known as STL and that is his id on reddit as well and he is active on C++ threads there.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The `transform` version is fine (somewhat by happenstance); the temporary regex isn't destroyed until the end of the full expression, i.e., the `;`, after the `transform` call is complete.

Comment: @T.C.: Ah, good point--if I'd been thinking, I'd have realized that.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a bug. See [LWG 2329 regex_match()/regex_search() with match_results should forbid temporary strings](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2329). This construct exhibits undefined behavior since it binds a temporary regex to const regex& and stores a pointer to it.

Also see [C++14 STL Features, Fixes, And Breaking Changes In Visual Studio 14 CTP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/06/c-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx) where this is listed as a fix.

Comment: Note that LWG 2329 is about temporary `string`s *not* temporary `regex`s. What you're looking for is [LWG 2332](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2332). If Visual Studio's implementation of LWG 2332 realy deleted the `move` constructor for the `regex` it should have failed to compile.