# Simple std::regex_search() code won't compile with Apple clang++ -std=c++14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, clang++

Here is the MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

std::string s()
{
    return "test";
}

int main()
{
    static const std::regex regex(R"(\w)");
    std::smatch smatch;

    if (std::regex_search(s(), smatch, regex)) {
        std::cout << smatch[0] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine with:

> $ clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp

but not with:

> $ clang++ -std=c++14 main.cpp

Error message in the later case (with -std=c++14):

```
main.cpp:14:9: error: call to deleted function 'regex_search'
    if (std::regex_search(s(), smatch, regex)) {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:5998:1: note: 
      candidate function [with _ST = std::__1::char_traits<char>, _SA = std::__1::allocator<char>,
      _Ap = std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char *> > >, _Cp =
      char, _Tp = std::__1::regex_traits<char>] has been explicitly deleted
regex_search(const basic_string<_Cp, _ST, _SA>&& __s,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:2876:5: note: 
      candidate function [with _ST = std::__1::char_traits<char>, _SA = std::__1::allocator<char>,
      _Ap = std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char *> > >, _Cp =
      char, _Tp = std::__1::regex_traits<char>]
    regex_search(const basic_string<_Cp, _ST, _SA>& __s,
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:2851:5: note: 
      candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_Bp'
      ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' vs. 'std::__1::match_results<std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char
      *>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char *> > > >')
    regex_search(_Bp, _Bp, const basic_regex<_Cp, _Tp>&,
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:2857:5: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _Cp *' against 'std::string' (aka
      'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
    regex_search(const _Cp*, const _Cp*,
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:2863:5: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _Cp *' against 'std::string' (aka
      'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
    regex_search(const _Cp*, match_results<const _Cp*, _Ap>&, const basic_regex<_Cp, _Tp>&,
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:2869:5: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_regex' against 'match_results'
    regex_search(const basic_string<_Cp, _ST, _SA>& __s,
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:5963:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'std::string' (aka
      'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
regex_search(const _CharT* __str, const basic_regex<_CharT, _Traits>& __e,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:2839:5: note: 
      candidate function template not viable: requires at least 4 arguments, but 3 were provided
    regex_search(_Bp, _Bp, match_results<_Bp, _Ap>&, const basic_regex<_Cp, _Tp>&,
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:2845:5: note: 
      candidate function template not viable: requires at least 4 arguments, but 3 were provided
    regex_search(const _Cp*, const _Cp*, match_results<const _Cp*, _Ap>&,
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/regex:2884:5: note: 
      candidate function template not viable: requires at least 4 arguments, but 3 were provided
    regex_search(__wrap_iter<_Iter> __first,
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Compiler version information:

```
$ clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

So, what's wrong?

Comment: Interesting to note that gcc/libstdc++ has this failing in both C++11 and C++14 which seems like a good thing since this is basically undefined behavior.

Comment: You know I was almost sure I had seen this issue before see: [Visual Studio regex_iterator Bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29895747/1708801) although this is with regex_iterator/regex_token_iterator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was a change going from C++11 to C++14 where [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) is no longer allowed to take a r-value

> ```
> template< class STraits, class SAlloc,
>           class Alloc, class CharT, class Traits >
> bool regex_search( const std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc>&&,
>                    std::match_results<
>                        typename std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc>::const_iterator, 
>                        Alloc>&,
>                    const std::basic_regex<CharT, Traits>&,
>                    std::regex_constants::match_flag_type flags =
>                        std::regex_constants::match_default ) = delete;
> ```

This was added as the overload that takes a `const std::string&`

> is prohibited from accepting temporary strings, otherwise this function populates match_results m with string iterators that become invalid immediately.

So you can no longer pass a temporary to `std::regex_search` as of C++14

To fix your code we would simply store the return from `s()` into a variable in main and use that to call `std::regex_search`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

std::string s()
{
    return "test";
}

int main()
{
    static const std::regex regex(R"(\w)");
    std::smatch smatch;

    auto search = s();
    if (std::regex_search(search, smatch, regex)) {
        std::cout << smatch[0] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79a1c5d0f5ac2031)</kbd>

Comment: So, I need to create a local std::sting variable in main(), initialise it by what is returned by s(), and then pass this variable into std::regex_search, right?

Comment: @Wildcat Yes.  Added to answer

Answer (score 7):

This changed between C++11 and C++14. If we go to the [cppreference section for std::regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) we can see that overload that takes an rvalue reference was deleted since C++14:

```
template< class STraits, class SAlloc,
          class Alloc, class CharT, class Traits > bool regex_search( const std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc>&&,
                   std::match_results<
                       typename std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc>::const_iterator,
                       Alloc
                   >&,
                   const std::basic_regex<CharT, Traits>&,
                   std::regex_constants::match_flag_type flags =
                       std::regex_constants::match_default ) = delete;
```

It was changed due to [LWG issue 2329: regex_match()/regex_search() with match_results should forbid temporary strings](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2329) which says (*emphasis mine*):

> Consider the following code:
>
> ```
> const regex r(R"(meow(\d+)\.txt)");
> smatch m;
> if (regex_match(dir_iter->path().filename().string(), m, r)) {
>   DoSomethingWith(m[1]);
> }
> ```
>
> This occasionally crashes. The problem is that
>   dir_iter->path().filename().string() returns a temporary string, **so
>   the match_results contains invalidated iterators into a destroyed
>   temporary string**.
>
> It's fine for regex_match/regex_search(str, reg) to accept temporary
>   strings, because they just return bool. **However, the overloads taking
>   match_results should forbid temporary strings**.

and indeed if we use a non-temporary:

```
std::string s1 = s() ;

if (std::regex_search(s1, smatch, regex)) {
//...
}
```

it compiles (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OqqPFrlxKimSz6sy)*) and no longer exhibits undefined behavior.

Interesting to note that gcc/libstdc++ has this overload deleted in C++11 mode as well [see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FNJD0yRvWQZM2WI6). Since this is undefined behavior it seems like a good solution.

This issue also pops up in other areas of the library see [Visual Studio regex_iterator Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29895747/1708801) which deals with the same issue but with `regex_iterator/regex_token_iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

This not a bug, but expected behaviour. 
The reason is that `s()` returns a temporary string, `regex_search` makes use of `regex_match` and consequently if a temporary string was utilized match results would contain iterators to a string that no longer exists. This would have been undefined behaviour. Thus, the committee abolished this `regex_search` overload in C++14.

You can also confirm in the standard *28.4 Header  synopsis [re.syn]*:

```
template <class ST, class SA, class Allocator, class charT, class traits>
bool regex_search(const basic_string<charT, ST, SA>&&,
match_results<
typename basic_string<charT, ST, SA>::const_iterator,
Allocator>&,
const basic_regex<charT, traits>&,
regex_constants::match_flag_type =
regex_constants::match_default) = delete;
```

As you can see the overload that takes a rvalue to a `basic_string` is marked deleted.