# Does experimental::basic_string_view<> work with rvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, string-view

I am not 100% that the following code is semantically correct:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/string_view>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "lvalue string";

    std::experimental::string_view view_lvalue(str);
    std::experimental::string_view view_rvalue(std::string{"rvalue string"});

    std::cout << view_lvalue << '\n' << view_rvalue << '\n';
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Wandbox</kbd>](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9hpWxsZdFGMpu4Kq)

**Question:** Can I legally bind a rvalue to [std::experimental::basic_string_view](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view), or is it just UB? If yes, how does it work? As far as I know, a rvalue does not bind to a `const` reference (which I assume the view holds to the original string) via the constructor, so I thought that at the end of the statement `std::experimental::string_view view_rvalue(std::string{"rvalue string"});` the reference will be dangling. Does `string_view` use a more sophisticated approach?

I am asking this because I am trying to write a similar view for some matrix class, and don't yet know how to deal with rvalues (I can disable them of course, but I don't think it's the best approach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cpprefernce is correct then this is UB.  [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view) has

> A typical implementation holds only two members: a pointer to constant `CharT` and a `size`.

And the constructor has

> Constructs a view of the first `str.size()` characters of the character array starting with the element pointed by `str.data()`.

So if `string_view` just points to the underlying char array of the provided string then we will have a dangling pointer once the expression ends and the temporary is destroyed.

As pointed out in the comments one reason this behavior may have been allowed is so you can pass a `string_view` to a function and construct that `string_view` from a temporary `string`

Comment: That's what I first thought, but then why not just `string_view(const string&&) = delete;`, which will disable rvalues?

Comment: @vsoftco Write an LWG issue :)

Comment: @T.C. I want first to make sure that it is indeed UB ;)

Comment: @vsoftco it is, but on second thought banning rvalues may significantly reduce usability for functions taking string view arguments.

Comment: @T.C. Can you give an example? You mean that `func(string_view(rvalue))` will be OK?

Comment: Do note that the [similar GSL type `string_span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) does explicitly disallow using rvalues in various cases, for precisely this reason. Of course, this makes it hard to use in some cases, as T.C. points out; you have to create an explicit temporary.

Comment: @vsoftco remember the standard doesn't always cath these things.  Like when they had to change regex_search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154890/simple-stdregex-search-code-wont-compile-with-apple-clang-std-c14/33155000#33155000

Comment: @vsoftco I think that example is one of the things T.C. was thinking of.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, I'm still a bit confused. Why will `func(string_view(rvalue))` work? The argument (i.e. the view) is copied into the parameter, which is later used inside the function. AFAIK, this should also be UB, as the original rvalue is long dead. Maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: @vsoftco The rvalue should exist till the end of the expression and having the function execute and return is part of the expression so the rvalue should be alive the entire time.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh yes, sure, my confusion. It's dead at `;`. So indeed it's OK, thanks.

Comment: @NicolBolas iirc string_span is read-write, though. So it's kinda like non-const/const lvalue reference.

Comment: @vsoftco `std::string f(); void g(string_view); g(f());`. In general, functions taking `string_view`s can't assume anything about the underlying string's lifetime anyway, so I'm not sure there's much point in banning creation from rvalues.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I see what you mean.