# Why do I get two different results while using sregex_iterator with a regex variable pattern vs a constructed pattern

Tags: c++, regex, stl

If I input "110110" in to the application, the first chunk prints out "1" while the second chunk prints out "2".

Why are the results different?

How can I construct the regex pattern in the function call?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;

    auto begin = sregex_iterator(s.begin(),s.end(),regex{R"(110)"});
    auto end = sregex_iterator();
    cout << distance(begin,end) << endl;

    const regex r(R"(110)");
    begin = sregex_iterator(s.begin(),s.end(),r);
    end = sregex_iterator();
    cout << distance(begin,end) << endl;
}
```

Comment: [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: pretty sure it is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154890/simple-stdregex-search-code-wont-compile-with-apple-clang-std-c14)

Comment: Yes, bits/stdc++.h... bad habit from quick typing code for comps. Feel free to substitute iostream and regex includes :)

Comment: Found this in the documentation for regex_iterator:
Notes
It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the std::basic_regex object passed to the iterator's constructor outlives the iterator. Because the iterator stores a pointer to the regex, incrementing the iterator after the regex was destroyed accesses a dangling pointer.

So I guess this is just a case where the compiler doesn't care and the programmer must be vigilant about dangling pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++14 fixed the interface by deleting the constructor:

```
regex_iterator(BidirIt, BidirIt,
               const regex_type&&,
               std::regex_constants::match_flag_type) = delete;
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the "delete" portion. But I am compiling with std=c++14 and -Wall and get no warnings building the application above. Does delete indicate that it should not build?

Comment: You should have an error [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b8abf0a1f3d4997).

Comment: Thanks.. I double checked with clang and do indeed get the error. Running gcc-4.9 results in no error. I guess the c++14 support in 4.9 isn't all there