# Concatenation of strings in C++ (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux

I want to concatenate three string in C++.

I have a vector `std::vector<std::string> my_list` where the filenames are stored. I want to add the directory and filename extension for each of the filenames in order to read binary the information from the file, so i do it like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < my_list.size(); i++) {
        std::string tmp = prefix + my_list[i] + suffix;
        std::ifstream file(tmp.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);
}
```

where **prefix** ist std::string prefix = "directory/" and **suffix** ist std::string suffix = ".foo".

And it works in Windows. However it doesn't work in Linux. 
Suffix overwrites "tmp"-string. It looks like `foo/y_file_timestamp` instead of `out/my_file_timestamp.foo`.

What should I do to prevent this overwriting?

Comment: Bluff! Can we see a [mcve]?

Comment: the code looks ok. The bug must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 7):

The bug is not in the code you showed us.

The problem is that your strings have unexpected characters in them, specifically *carriage returns* (`'\r'`) that cause the caret to return to the beginning of the line during output of your concatenated string to the terminal window.

Presumably this is a problem caused by careless parsing of input data with Windows-style line endings. You should normalise your data and be sure to strip *all* line-ending variants during parsing.

Always be sure to check the contents of your strings at the character-level when encountering a problem with string operations.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @BarryTheHatchet. I forgot to mention that vector `my_list` was filled this way:

```
std::string LIST_WITH_DATA = "data/list.scp"

const char* my_data = LIST_WITH_DATA.c_str();

std::ifstream my_file(my_data);

std::string my_line;

while (std::getline(my_file, my_line)) {

    my_list.push_back(my_line);

}
```

`data/list.scp` looks like:

```
file1/00001-a
file2/00001-b
file3/00001-c
file4/00001-d
```

`std::getline` was my problem.

The solution I found here: [Getting std :: ifstream to handle LF, CR, and CRLF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089231/getting-std-ifstream-to-handle-lf-cr-and-crlf)