# Program output differs between Windows and Linux. Why?

Tags: c++, linux, simulation

I run the code in both Windows and Linux. 
In Window, I can get result I intended but, in Linux, I get different result with one I get from Window.

What causes this difference and how to fix the code in Linux?

Thanks a lot! :) I attached the code, input, and result from both OS.

Below is my code; 
(This code is to reversely order the components with dots and differentiate components using a slash.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

string set_name = "6000k";

// in
string raw_file = set_name + "_filtered.txt";
// out
string set_file = set_name + "_filtered_dot.txt";

// main
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    string comp = ""; 
    string str; 

    vector<string> input_comp;
    vector<string> tmp_comp; 
    int input_order = 0;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(raw_file);

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(set_file);

    if (infile.fail()) // error handling
    {
        cout << "error; raw_file cannot be open..\n";
    }

    while (!infile.fail())
    {
        char c = infile.get();

        if (c == '\n' || c == '/')
        {
            if (comp != "") 
            {
                input_comp.push_back(comp);
            }

            int num = input_comp.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
            {
                int idx = (num - 1) - j;
                outfile << "/" << input_comp[idx];
            }

            if (c == '\n')
            {
                outfile << "/" << endl;
            }

            input_comp.clear();
            str = "";
            comp = "";
        }
        else if (c == '.')
        {
            if (comp != "") 
            {
                input_comp.push_back(comp);
            }

            comp = "";
        }
        else 
        {
            str = c;
            comp = comp + str;
        }

    }

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

This is inputs in 'raw_file' declared in code;

```
/blog.sina.com.cn/mouzhongshao
/blogs.yahoo.co.jp/junkii3/11821140.html
/allplayboys.imgur.com
```

This is result from Window; (This is what I want to get from above code)

```
/cn/com/sina/blog/mouzhongshao/
/jp/co/yahoo/blogs/junkii3/html/11821140/
/com/imgur/allplayboys/
```

This is result from Linux; (unexpected result)

```
/cn/com/sina/blog/mouzhongshao
/
/jp/co/yahoo/blogs/junkii3/html
/11821140/
/com
/imgur/allplayboys/
```

Comment: `while (!infile.fail())` checks for failure before reading. Do not expect this to work.

Comment: The final value seems to include the newline on linux (e.g. `"html\n"` instead of just `"html"`)

Comment: If the input file was created on windows it will contain the windows end of line: \r\n. This will mess up your output under Linux because it will print the \r.

Comment: `\r ` vs `\n` vs `\r\n` vs `\n\r` vs other combinations. Beware your assumptions about file formats.

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses a compound end of line: carriage return and line feed (`\r\n`). When a C++ file stream opened a file in text mode, the default, finds `\r\n`, it silently converts it to `\n`.

Linux only uses line feed (`\n`). When the file stream finds `\r\n`, the `\r` is treated like a regular character and passed to the parser.

So on Linux `/blog.sina.com.cn/mouzhongshao\r\n` is broken up into

```
<empty>
blog
sina
com
cn
mouzhongshao\r
```

And depending on how the console handles the `\r` may print

```
/cn/com/sina/blog/mouzhongshao
/
```

or

```
/cn/com/sina/blog/mouzhongshao
```

with the carriage return moving the cursor back to the beginning of the line and the overwriting the first `/` with the last.

The easy solution is to convert the input file to Linux-style line endings. Many Linux text editors have a DOS to Unix format conversion utility built in. A dos2unix application is also widely available. If all else fails, rewrite the file under Linux.

A longer solution is to make both Windows and Linux behave the same. Many examples of this already exist. Here is one: [Getting std :: ifstream to handle LF, CR, and CRLF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089231/getting-std-ifstream-to-handle-lf-cr-and-crlf)

Also watch out for `while (!infile.fail())` as it tests for readability before reading, meaning all subsequent reads may fail and you won't know. More on that here: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

To resolve this, do not immediately cast the result of `infile.get();` to a `char` Keep it an `int` long enough to see if the result is `Traits::eof()` before using the value as a `char`.

Comment: I wrote the code in Window, that is why this difference is caused. I did not think of different line ending(\r\n and \n) between Window and Linux. Thanks for clear explanation! :)