# std::getline() reads carriage return \r into the string, how to avoid that?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I need to read all attributes from a tеxt file that looks like the following for one `Stern` (engl.: Star) object. I need to replace the string `"leer"` with `""` but there can also be a valid string which shouldn't be replaced with `""`.

I.e for another `Stern` object there could be `"leer"` instead of `"Sol"` as well.

**Problem:**
The problem is it doesn't replace the `"leer"` with the `""`. And it seems like it saves `"leer\\r"` in the object instead of only `"leer"` but I tried to replace `"leer\\r"` as well and it still doesn`t work.

This is one `Stern` in the text file that should be read:

```
0
Sol
0.000005
0.000000
0.000000
leer
1
0
```

And this is my `operator >>` to read it:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Stern& obj)
{
    string dummy;
    is >> obj.m_ID;
    getline(is, dummy);
    getline(is, obj.m_Bez);

    if (obj.m_Bez == "leer")
        obj.m_Bez = "";

    is >> obj.m_xKoord >> obj.m_yKoord >> obj.m_zKoord;
    getline(is,dummy);
    getline(is,obj.m_Sternbild);

    if (obj.m_Sternbild == "leer")
        obj.m_Sternbild = "";

    is >> obj.m_Index >> obj.m_PrimID;

    return is;
}
```

Stern.h:

```
#ifndef STERN_H
#define STERN_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Stern
{
public:
    Stern();
    // 2.a)
    //Stern(int m_ID, string m_Bez, float m_xKoord, float m_yKoord, float m_zKoord, string m_Sternbild, int m_Index, int m_PrimID); 
    virtual ~Stern();

    void print() const; // 1.b)
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Stern& obj); // 1.b)i.
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Stern& obj);


private:
    int m_ID;
    string m_Bez;
    float m_xKoord;
    float m_yKoord;
    float m_zKoord;
    string m_Sternbild;
    int m_Index;
    int m_PrimID;
};

#endif /* STERN_H */
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you show?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't replace the "leer" with the ""
And it seems like it saves "leer\\r" in the object instead of only "leer" 
but I tried to replace "leer\\r" as well and it still doesn`t work.

Comment: If the input is the same as the one from your description then I guess it's because of the whitespace before the "leer" word? Don't forget you are using `getline(is, obj.m_Bez);` and that doesn't remove the whitespace. Try triming the string first then check for equality.

Comment: The exact values saved are:

m_ID: 0
m_Bez: "Sol\\r"
m_xKoord:4.99999987e-06

Comment: And if you step through the code line by line in a debugger, what do you notice then? Are the values you read the correct ones, the ones you expect?

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that `m_Sternbild` is a `char*`.

Comment: Also, can you tell us what `Stern` is? How is it defined? Preferably please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: They are the correct values when I take a look into  my Stern obj except the strings do have \\r behind them  but thats because I can't figure out how to convert my dos to a unix file in my Virtual Machine ( Ubuntu(64bit)

I just can`t replace the "leer" / "leer\\r" with my if()

Comment: How about comparing with `"leer\r"` as well?

Comment: @CraigHarrison Install `dos2unix` on your Ubuntu (if it's not already there) and convert with it. (And don't use the backtick character as an apostrophe.)

Comment: Stern is basically a star with attributes which is later pushbacked into list<Stern> l_stars (which is a priv attribute of my galaxy class)

Comment: @CraigHarrison Post (in the question) the actual definition of `Stern`, not a description of what it basically is.

Comment: This should do then? 

if (obj.m_Sternbild == "leer\\r" || obj.m_Sternbild == "leer\r" || obj.m_Sternbild == "leer")
       obj.m_Sternbild = "";

@molbdnilo I`m fairly new to Ubuntu and only use it because our University offered a virtual machine with everything installed for this current semester. How do I install dos2unix?

Comment: @CraigHarrison better use `obj.m_Sternbild.erase(std::remove(obj.m_Sternbild.begin(), obj.m_Sternbild.end(), '\r'), obj.m_Sternbild.end());` then compare imo.

Comment: @CraigHarrison: `dos2unix` is already installed on Ubuntu.

Comment: I have posted the whole project in the question now.

Comment: @CraigHarrison also instead of '\r' try with '\n' too.

Comment: @AndreKampling So I open my terminal type "dos2unix /home/stud/stars-newline-leer.txt" 
It only tells me command not found

Comment: @molbdnilo is a string, sorry for letting you guess

Comment: @CraigHarrison: Sorry I though that Ubuntu would have been shipped with something such elementary: `sudo apt-get install tofrodos` will install it then.

Comment: @AndreKampling I installed it but dos2unix still seems to be non existent

Comment: @CraigHarrison: Then use `fromdos` as command it will do the same, if that doesn't work you didn't install it.

Comment: @AndreKampling Thanks a lot! That worked! Now it also correctly replaces the string m_Sternbild with my if()

Comment: @CraigHarrison: You should try to understand why it's working now. The [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) characters in Windows/Unix are different. On Windows it's `CR+LF` and on Unix it's `LF`. The `tofrodos` tool can convert files between them. To check a file use the `file` command.

Comment: I did understand that my problem is the \\r on the end of the strings and that Windows and Unix files have different newlines but I couldnt figure out how to change them. And I still cant understand why my if (obj.m_Sternbild == "leer\\r") didn`t work because imo it should have worked?
When I try to check my stars-newline-leer.txt with "file stars-newline-leer.txt" it only says stars-newline-leer.txt:ASCII text and after I convert it it says the same.

Comment: Hey folks---**can we get some answers going here**, instead of having an extended discussion in the comments? If you need to add information, [edit] it into your question.

Comment: @CraigHarrison: If a question on StackOverflow is solved you don't write it to the tilte neither the text. You can accept an answer that is given see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419.

Comment: There must be a secret cabal of evildoers sneaking around the internets, teaching beginners to write `while (!file.eof())`. [Don't do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in Windows a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is represented as `CR + LF` which is: `"\r\n"` and in Unix it is `LF` which is just `"\n"`.
Your [`std::getline(...)` command](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) is reading till the `"\n"` in `"leer\r\n"` and discards the `"\n"`, your resulting string will be:

```
"leer\r"
```

To solve this problem and convert files between Unix/Windows there are the 2 tools [`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) and [`unix2dos`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unix2dos). The Ubuntu equivalents are [`fromdos`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/fromdos.1.html) and [`todos`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/todos.1.html), you will need `fromdos` to convert your Windows text file to a Unix text file.

To test wether a file uses `CR + LF` or `LF` you can do:

> ```
> dos2unix < myfile.txt | cmp -s - myfile.txt
> ```

which was ansered here on the [Unix & Linux StackExchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79757).

---

> And it seems like it saves `"leer\\r"` in the object instead of only `"leer"` but I tried to replace `"leer\\r"` as well and it still doesn`t work. I still cant understand why my `if (obj.m_Sternbild == "leer\\r")` didn`t work because imo it should have worked?

It should be:

```
if (obj.m_Sternbild == "leer\r")
```

without escaping the backslash `\`, because `\r` is read into the string.

**Edit:**

As **@FreelanceConsultant** in the comment below write: The above answer is not a general solution. Because a binary compiled either on Windows or Unix should work for text files for both platforms.

There are two solutions for that.

The obvious one is, to compare against two different versions of the input. With `std::getline` the Windows result is `"leer\r"` and Unix result is `"leer"`.

```
if (obj.m_Sternbild == "leer\r" || obj.m_Sternbild == "leer")
```

Another solution would be to normalize the newline representation to one form and only check against that. It is a matter of taste and performance, because you would need to create new strings. See [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72365365/8051589) as example.

Comment: This isn't really a solution. Some text files are created on Unix systems, some are created on Windows systems. Regardless of which platform a binary is compiled for, it should work with both text files created on Windows systems or Linux systems.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: Yes, you are right. It should work without any additional steps on the input file on Unix or Windows. To achieve that, it is needed to compare against both string versions (`if (obj.m_Sternbild == "leer\r" || obj.m_Sternbild == "leer")`) or to normalize it for the check in his own code without any program.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this to remove any unwanted characters returned by `std::getline`.

```
// std::string s;
// std::getline(input, s);
s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '\r' ), s.end());
s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '\n' ), s.end());
```

This works on Linux systems where the input file is formatted with line endings `CRLF`. This is because, on Linux systems, `std::getline` is searching for the `\n` character, hence it returns an extra `\r` at the end of each line.

I would not expect this to work exactly as you might anticipate on other systems. For example, it **might** be the case that:

- On OS X, `getline` **probably** searches for `\r`, meaning subsequent calls return a string which **starts** with `\n`. (The above will **probably** still work, because you still erase the `\n`.
- On Windows, `getline` searches for `\r\n`. If a file was produced on OS X or Linux, I would **assume** `getline` fails to split the input into different lines, and just returns the entire input.
- I'm not 100% sure about the above two points and haven't tested either case, because I don't happen to have an OS X system available, or a Windows system setup for development work.

Comment: With C++20:
std::erase(s, '\r');
std::erase(s, '\n');

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2022 in Windows and "getline" is returning "\r". "getline" should have an option for choosing multiple line endings (strings and characters). I landed on this page hoping someone had made such a function. Guess I'm out of luck... 

Comment: @andrepacheco you could use the above two lines and wrap them in a function to do that

Comment: A big correction: I think I'm getting the "\r" because I created the stream in binary mode, I think text mode should work for same-OS text files. Anyway, I think I've found my wanted function in the selected answer of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089231/getting-std-ifstream-to-handle-lf-cr-and-crlf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089231/getting-std-ifstream-to-handle-lf-cr-and-crlf). Haven't tried it though...

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Thanks for your answer but that would not have the performance I am looking for. 

Comment: @andrepacheco if you have some specific usecase which requires some specific level of performance which erase-remove style algorithms don't provide (assuming you did measure it and found this to be the case and didn't just assume) then you are better off asking a specific question about this rather than adding a comment to an existing question which isn't relevant to your use case

Answer (score 1):

> And it seems like it saves "leer\r" in the object instead of only
>   "leer"

You can either trim the string you get from `getline` or use `getline` in combination with a `stringstream` :

```
 std::string line;
 getline(is,line);
 std::stringstream ss(line);
 std::string trimmed_string;
 ss >> trimmed_string;
```

Now `trimmed_string` will contain only the desired string, no end line, trainling or leading whitespace or other stuff.

PS: this only works if the string you want to read does not contain whitespace itself. If thats the case you have to resort to a bit more involved massaging of the string you get from `getline` or choose some special character that you can replace with whitespaces after reading (eg read "Alpha_Centauri" and then replace "_" with " " to get "Alpha Centauri").

Comment: Yes the problem is that there are m_Bez (basically the name of  the star)
which look like this: "96 G. Psc"
And I wouldnt be allowed to change the txt file in any way.

Comment: @CraigHarrison then unfortunately my answer does not help. Maybe I will edit it later....

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Just note that `std::getline()` will read an entire line as-is up to the line break, whereas `ss >>` will skip leading whitespace and then read up to the first whitespace or end-of-string, whichever occurs first. So, `ss >>` is not just trimming if the line has any non-leading/trailing space in it before the line break. You would be chopping off actual data. Trimming involves scanning and removing only leading + trailing whitespace, not any whitespace in the middle.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thats what my PS is about. I was hoping that a simple solution can help and didnt have time yet to improve the answer

Comment: @idclev463035818 You could still use your `stringstream` approach, just use `std::getline()` instead of `operator>>`, explicitly telling `getline()` to use `'\r'` as a delimiter. Or, you could forgo the `stringstream` and simply check if the last character in the `line` string is `'\r'` and if so then erase it.