# Reading words from a text file: weird behaviour

Tags: c++

I'm running the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream input_file(argv[1]);
    vector<string> words;
    string line;

    while(getline(input_file, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl;
        words.push_back(line);
    }
    input_file.close();

    cout << "First and last word: " << words[0] << " " << words.back() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

using the following text file as an input

```
permission
copper
operation
cop
rationale
rest
```

and I get the following output in terminal

```
permission
copper
operation
cop
rationale
rest

 rest and last word: permission
```

Why is the last word `words.back()` printed at the beginning of the line while erasing some of the text?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956271/stdgetline-reads-carriage-return-r-into-the-string-how-to-avoid-that

Comment: `ifstream input_file(argv[1]);` -- Basically, you told a fib to the file I/O library and stated the file is a text file, when it isn't a text file.  Once you did that, expect all sorts of weird things to happen.

Comment: I'm surprised you get that extra line, though...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It _is_ a text file, and telling the lib that it's a binary file won't fix this issue.

Comment: What I am saying is that as far as the I/O library is concerned, the file is not what would be considered a text file due to the line endings.  It essentially is a "binary" file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your file has Windows line-endings (`"\r\n"`) and you're on Linux or Mac (which doesn't translate these into `"\n"`).

`std::getline` is only trimming the `'\n'`s for you. So, `\r` is left at the end of each of your strings; in many consoles, `'\r'` moves the write cursor to the start of the line. Then, the `" " << words.back()` part overwrites the already-written `"First and last word: " << words[0]` part.

---

#### Example:

- First word is `permission␍`
- Last word is `rest␍`

*(Note the `␍` control character at the end of each word!)*

```
┌───────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────┐
│                   │  ⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭                               │
│ Write "First"     │  First                               │
│                   │       ꕯ                              │
├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┼┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┤
│                   │       ⭭⭭⭭⭭                           │
│ Write " and"      │  First·and                           │
│                   │           ꕯ                          │
├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┼┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┤
│                   │           ⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭                      │
│ Write " last"     │  First·and·last                      │
│                   │                ꕯ                     │
├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┼┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┤
│                   │                ⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭                │
│ Write " word:"    │  First·and·last·word:                │
│                   │                      ꕯ               │
├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┼┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┤
│                   │                      ⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭⭭␍    │
│ Write first word  │  First·and·last·word:·permission     │
│                   │  ꕯ                                   │
├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┼┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┤
│                   │  ⭭                                   │
│ Write " "         │  ·irst·and·last·word:·permission     │
│                   │   ꕯ                                  │
├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┼┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┤
│                   │   ⭭⭭⭭⭭␍                              │
│ Write last word   │  ·rest·and·last·word:·permission     │
│                   │  ꕯ                                   │
└───────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

#### Solution

You can strip this from the end of each line yourself, [or preprocess the file externally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45957854/4386278).