# Why result from std::getline() is not as expected

Tags: c++, getline

I'm extracting some data from a text file and put them in 2 vectors but the output of std::getline() is not as I expected. Here's the code:

```
std::vector<std::string> v1;
std::vector<std::string> v2;

const char* filename = "words.txt";
std::ifstream fin(filename);
  
if (!fin) {
    throw "Bad file name!";
}
else {
    // File is good
    std::string temp;
    while (std::getline(fin, temp)) {
      std::cout << "(((Temp: " << temp << ")))" << std::endl;
      v1.push_back(temp.substr(0, temp.find(' ')));
      // Erase first character
      temp.erase(0, temp.find(' ') + 1);
      // Erase spaces
      v2.push_back(temp.substr(temp.find_first_not_of(' '),temp.find_last_not_of(' ') - temp.find_first_not_of(' ') + 1));
    }
}

// output v1:
std::cout << "\nValues of v1:\n";
for (auto word : v1){
   std::cout << "(((" << word << ")))" << std::endl;
}

// output v2:
std::cout << "\nValues of v2:\n";
for (auto word : v2){
   std::cout << "(((" << word << ")))" << std::endl;
}
```

Here's the "words.txt":

```
a    A
b        B
c    C
d         D
e       E
```

The real words.txt is more complicated but similar.

And here's the output:

```
)))Temp: a    A
)))Temp: b        B
)))Temp: c    C
)))Temp: d         D
)))Temp: e       E

Values of v1:
(((a)))
(((b)))
(((c)))
(((d)))
(((e)))

Values of v2:
)))A
)))B
)))C
)))D
)))E
```

Why is there a difference in the output from each line read from the file and between the 2 vectors?

Comment: Because this is what the program does? It's fairly complicated way of removing the intervening whitespace between the two words on each line. It's a pretty fragile, inefficient, and error-prone way of doing so, but that's what it does.

Comment: Is there any way around this? I need the data in the second vector but this kinda messes up all of them and I cannot  use it the way I want.

Comment: Looks like your words.txt file has CRLF end-of-lines.  You might want to trim the CR off the end of the line, first thing after doing the getline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `v2`, the values end with a carriage return (`\r`). When this is printed to the terminal, it makes the cursor go back to the beginning of the line, so the `)))` is printed over top of the `(((`. The same thing happens when the `temp` values are displayed, because it displays the entire line.

Please also see [Getting std :: ifstream to handle LF, CR, and CRLF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089231/getting-std-ifstream-to-handle-lf-cr-and-crlf) .

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally forgot about the \r in each line.